# extract all keys of a dictionary of dictionaries as a list or np.array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, dictionary

**Input**: a dictionary of dictionaries where all keys are integers. Values in the nested dictionaries are irrelevant.

**Desired output**: a list or a `np.array` of the `(outer_key, inner_key)` pairs.

Example:

```
dict_of_dicts = {0: {1: "crap", 2: "crap", 3: "crap"}, 4: {5: "crap", 1: "crap"}}
```

I need an output such as

```
key_pairs = [(0,1), (0,2), (0,3), (4,5), (4,1)]
```

or

```
import numpy as np 
key_pairs = np.array([[0,1], [0,2], [0,3], [4,5], [4,1]])
```

The order of the pairs is not important, obviously (`dict_of_dicts` is not ordered, after all), so

```
key_pairs = np.array([[0,2], [0,1], [0,3], [4,5], [4,1]])
```

would still work, for example. Concerning speed, on one hand this will have to be executed a few hundred thousands of times, but on the other all dicts of dicts are fairly small (about a dozen of key pairs). Thus, readability would matter more than speed, I guess. Having both would be excellent, of course

Comment: What exactly is your question about this task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a nested list comprehension:

```
key_pairs = [(k1, k2) for k1, v in dict_of_dicts.items() for k2 in v.keys()]
print(key_pairs)
```

Output:

```
[(0, 1), (0, 2), (0, 3), (4, 5), (4, 1)]
```

Comment: TIL that you can nest `for` statements in list comprehensions. Thanks!